# Why when I create normal Segue to show the next ViewController it make it like this in the leagueVC Not a fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, segue, viewcontroller

Why when I create normal Segue to show the next ViewController it make it like this in the leagueVC Not a fullscreen ?

I want yo show the next screen as fullscreen by using the segue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the presentation mode on your segue. You can change it in the attributes inspector with the "Kind" dropdown menu:

You want "Present Modally". A "Presentation" dropdown will appear, which you should set to "Full Screen".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to show the next screen as fullscreen by using the segue:

**Method 1:**

Step 1: Select the segue.

Step 2: Go to the Attributes inspector.

Step 3: Go to the Kind dropdown menu and select "Show (e.g. Push)".

[image]

**Method 2:**

Step 1: Select the segue.

Step 2: Go to the Attributes inspector.

Step 3: Go to the Kind dropdown menu and select "Present Modally"

[image]

Step 4: Go to the Presentation dropdown menu and select "Full Screen"

[image]